# Google Cloud Debugger thread "can't continue"

Tags: java, stackdriver, micronaut, google-cloud-debugger

I'm trying to activate the google cloud debugger agent in my micronaut based java app in GKE. But as you may have guessed, it does not work and I can't see my app in the debugger tool in the cloud console.

The container entry point is: `[java, -agentpath:/cdbg_java_agent.so=--logtostderr=1, -Dcom.google.cdbg.module=mymodule, -Dcom.google.cdbg.version=123, -cp, /app/resources:/app/classes:/app/libs/*, com.example.Application]`.

I see these logs from the container:

```
I1015 07:52:41.962275     6 jvmti_globals.cc:330] Build time: Sep  5 2019 11:40:41
I1015 07:52:41.962328     6 jvmti_agent.cc:159] Java debuglet initialization started
I1015 07:52:41.962790     6 jvmti_agent.cc:193] Java debuglet initialization completed
I1015 07:52:42.099573     6 jvmti_agent.cc:204] Java VM started
I1015 07:52:42.111140     6 jvmti_agent.cc:214] JvmtiAgent::JvmtiOnVMInit initialization time: 11578 microseconds
I1015 07:52:42.111268    14 jvmti_agent_thread.cc:99] Agent thread started: CloudDebugger_main_worker_thread
E1015 07:52:42.111346    14 jvmti_agent.cc:339] Internals could not be initialized
E1015 07:52:42.111358    14 worker.cc:123] Agent initialization failed: debugger thread can't continue.
I1015 07:52:42.111362    14 jvmti_agent_thread.cc:103] Agent thread exited: CloudDebugger_main_worker_thread
```

It would be interesting to know why "Internals could not be initialized". Is there a way to increase the logging level?
How else can I find out why the debugger thread dies?

Comment: Hi. There are no verbosity options as of now. The error you're facing is just generic and might have multiple causes. I'd go either to report it to the [support team](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/getting-support#get_a_google_support_package) (if you're in the GCP trial you'll get basic support for free) or open an [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187252&template=0) with more details on your setup for them to take a look. This might be an issue in the agent itself but here is hard to debug.